# MatrixRank of a large but sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, memory

I want to find the rank of a very sparse, quite rectangular matrix `mat`, but I'm running out of RAM (I have 16 GB) if I try to use `MatrixRank` or `RowReduce`. The particular matrix I am considering is 44216 by 5958 and its `Tally` is

```
Tally@Flatten@Normal@mat
```

> {{1, 89348}, {0, 263290898}, {-1, 58682}}

I have also tried to produce the Gram matrix

```
gram = Transpose[mat].mat
```

since it has the same rank, but this matrix is obviously much less sparse. I also run out of RAM trying to do `MatrixRank[gram]`.

Also, should one take different approaches if the rank can be assumed to be small, or on the other hand, large (almost full rank)?

Comment: Have you tried using `SingularValueList[]`?

Comment: The notes on internal implementations states that "`PseudoInverse`, `NullSpace`, and `MatrixRank` are based on `SingularValueDecomposition`." Doesn't that mean that I effectively have? :p I'll test it shortly.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't asking you to compute the entire decomposition; just the singular values. :P

Comment: True ;) `MemoryConstrained[si = SingularValueList[gram];, 10000000000]` is running now (using `mat` didn't work as expected), and it doesn't seem to eat memory as quickly as `MatrixRank`. I'll post again when it completes/aborts.

Comment: Argh, no!!!1! You don't apply the SVD to the Gram matrix; apply it to the original one! Can you elaborate on "didn't work as expected"? Try `SingularValueList[N[mat]]`. If need be, specify the second argument.

Comment: "Didn't work as expected" as in "almost instantly ate all my RAM"... Since `SingularValueList` works with dense matrices (it prints a message saying this) and `mat` is roughly 8 times as large as `gram` I wasn't so surprised... But maybe I should have been?

Comment: Okay, as I said, you might want to look into the second argument…

Comment: Since the rank equals the number of nonzero singular values, and `SingularValueList` only returns nonzero SVs, do you mean to increment the second argument until no new SVs are found?

Comment: Yes, something like that. What gets zeroed of course depends on the `Tolerance` setting.